# Load model as an input layer and the whole model without any detail

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I would appreciate if someone can help me with my problem. I have trained and saved a model. Then, I want to load it again and make it untrainable. However, when I load it, it shows only an input layer plus the model as a subset. The following is my summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 9)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
FORWARD (Model)              (None, 65, 6)             459486    
=================================================================
Total params: 459,486
Trainable params: 459,486
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

and this is the part of code when I load it:

```
if trained_model_path is not None:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(trained_model_path,
                                       custom_objects={'BilinearUpsampling1D':BilinearUpsampling1D})
    model.trainable = False
```

Firstly, I want to know why I do not have a detailed summary of my loaded model which is saved using a simple model_save command.

Secondly, when I set my variables to be untrainable, it will show in the summary that I have double amount of parameters which half of them are trainable and the other half are not as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 9)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
FORWARD (Model)              (None, 65, 6)             459486    
=================================================================
Total params: 918,972
Trainable params: 459,486
Non-trainable params: 459,486
_________________________________________________________________
```

I believe this comes from the fact that my loaded model here is a submodel of the original one. However, I have no idea. Please let me know if someone can help me in this regard.

Thank you so much.
Regards,

P.S. I am using tensorflow 2.

Comment: I just fixed my problem regarding my model. Now, when I say model.summary(), it shows everything in details. But still, when I want to deactivate training, I will get the following:
Total params: 918,972
Trainable params: 459,486
Non-trainable params: 459,486

instead of :
Total params: 459,486
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 459,486

Comment: This sounds like a Bug. I have filed an Issue in Github, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37531.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the convincing workaround but if we use `model.compile()` after `model.trainable = False`, it is displaying the correct number of Total Number of Parameters.

Please find the working code below:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.1

import tensorflow as tf

from zipfile import ZipFile
zip_file = ZipFile('Resume_Classification_Model.zip', 'r')
zip_file.extractall('Resume_Classification_Model')

New_Model = tf.keras.models.load_model("Resume_Classification_Model/Resume_Classification_Model/1")

New_Model.summary()

New_Model = tf.keras.models.load_model("Resume_Classification_Model/Resume_Classification_Model/1")

New_Model.trainable= False

New_Model.compile()

# Now, observe the Total Number of Parameters
New_Model.summary()
```

To stay updated about this, you can refer this [Github Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37531).